# Проверить 2 массива на одинаковые значения

Tags: php

**Доброго времени суток.**
Есть два массива.
Нужно проверить Array1 значение 'NAME' с Array2 значение 'NAME' на совпадение.
Если имена не совпадают то внести в третий массив те имена которых нет в Array2
Пробывал разные варианты, не получилось.
Так же, в Array1 в будущем будут добавляться новые записи, т.е. будут старые 
категории и к ним же будут добавлены новые категории, и так же новые записи могут быть добавлены в середине файла, таким образом будет смещение индексов в массиве, по этому варианты с методами array_diff_assoc, array_udiff_assoc и им подобные которые проверяют по индексам, не срабатывают. (По крайней мере у меня не получилось) 
Уже несколько дней пробую, пока не получается =)
Может кто делал подобные задачи, поделитесь пожалуйста опытом =).
Array1: `Array
    (
        [ACTIVE] => Y
        [NAME] => Сварочное оборудование
    )
    Array
    (
        [ACTIVE] => Y
        [NAME] => Test category
    )
    Array
    (
        [ACTIVE] => Y
        [NAME] => Стабилизаторы напряжения
    )`

Array2: `Array
    (
        [ID] => 1429
        [NAME] => Сварочное оборудование
        [DESCRIPTION] => 
        [DESCRIPTION_TYPE] => text
        [SORT] => 500
    )
    Array
    (
        [ID] => 1429
        [NAME] => Стабилизаторы напряжения
        [DESCRIPTION] => 
        [DESCRIPTION_TYPE] => text
        [SORT] => 500 
    )
    Array
    (
        [ID] => 1429
        [NAME] => Садовая техника
        [DESCRIPTION] => 
        [DESCRIPTION_TYPE] => text
        [SORT] => 500 
    )`

Comment: Используйте [array_diff_uassoc](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-uassoc.php) с соответствующей коллбэк-функцией, сравнивающей требуемые элементы массивов.

Comment: @Akina, возвращает пустой массив.

Comment: Значит, где-то что-то неверно делаете. Функция-то проверена кучей разработчиков...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если совсем прямолинейно:

```
 $array1=[
    ['NAME'=>1,'VAL'=>11],
    ['NAME'=>2,'VAL'=>22],
    ['NAME'=>3,'VAL'=>33],
    ['NAME'=>4,'VAL'=>44],
    ];
$array2=[
    ['NAME'=>5,'VAL'=>55],
    ['NAME'=>6,'VAL'=>66],
    ['NAME'=>3,'VAL'=>33],
    ['NAME'=>4,'VAL'=>44],
    ['NAME'=>7,'VAL'=>77],
    ];    
$array3=[];

foreach($array2 as $row2){
    $flag=0;
    foreach($array1 as $row1){
        if($row1['NAME']==$row2['NAME']){
            $flag=1;
            break 1;
        };
    }
    if($flag===0)$array3[]=$row2;
}
var_dump($array3);
```

Результат: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5be967c3a9eb82cfc92a0391b3c9a13fa5cc99ed

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Но в файле могут быть несколько новых записей, а в вашем варианте после первого совпадения цикл остановится и не дойдет до другого расхождения.

Comment: ух ож этот  Битрикс

Comment: @Dolphin верно ошибка... другой вариант: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5be967c3a9eb82cfc92a0391b3c9a13fa5cc99ed
Топик поправил

Comment: @Pavel Спасибо, все отлично. Точный вариант. Очень помогли.